# Secure ASP.NET Core 6 application back-end code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

Is it possible to generate a DLL only from the *.cs files of the project and then remove them and deliver the DLL + rest of the files including the .cshtml files (views) for the client to have autonomy to edit the front? What kind of changes would I need to make to the project, would I need to keep 1 separate full version to be able to generate this DLL and a second project where I would have the DLL + views .cshtml? Do I need to reference this DLL somewhere? Would it be in the *.csproj file?

I recently decided to study ASP.NET Core 6 and ended up creating a very simple system that has several functions such as login, logout, user registration, customer registration, company registration, product registration, all of this is working perfectly, I used the scaffold of aspnet code generator + Entity Framework to generate Create, Delete, Details, Edit, Index and Migrations pages from Models (code first), I tested it with Sqlite initially and then with SqlServer, the system is OK, I can compile it in debug and release/publish, I can put it in production and send it to the client and it runs there without problems, this would be the default scenario where I would sell the solution without it having access to any source code (I won't go into details like reverse engineering , security, protection, etc..., as it is not the purpose of this question), what I need is for me to be able to edit the project for him so that he can edit only the *.cshtml files by modifying the i information from the front as I see fit and generate a new executable for the project, when he needs changes to the backend I would do it for him and charge for upgrades or not charge depending on the type of change.

Comment: Though you can make a `dll` of a individual `.cs` however, you cannot do it in a way where you can only create `dlls` for `cs` files only. All `.Net` application has same mechanism when you would publish it it will create all the source file as `dll`. On the other hands, you cannot modify anything on the `dlls` even you can do in some extent but that might not work as expected. For any kind of changes and modification you always need to work on the source code and then publish again. So far this is the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to deploy your application with [Razor Runtime Compilation Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

If you enable this, the .cshtml files that are deployed would be compiled at runtime, meaning that you could manipulate them on the fly without a visual studio recompile.

This is not enabled by default, so you will need to do a few things.  First you will need to install the NuGet package for this

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

Then you will need to add a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` in your builder when you add either MVC or Razor Pages to your project.

For Razor Pages it would be similar to the following

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

You cannot do this if you are using Blazor